# How can I define primary key with External table Sql Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on multiple azure sql databases and trying to join data using Elastic query.

1. I created external tables.
2. When I try to create entity from EF Core. this fails and I am getting below error.

Unable to identify the primary key for table 'xxxx'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'xxxx'.

How can I create primary key for external table or how can I have entity for external table with EF Core.

Comment: Your asking how to create a primary key on a table?

Comment: Yes, but primary key on Sql Server "External table" not with regular tables, or how I can create entity for "External table" with EF core. Or is there any way to query with dbcontext to "External Tables"?

Comment: Are you talking about PolyBase? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Have you tried defining key for your entity?

Comment: William Xifaras, yes, exactly I am looking something for PolyBase.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not currently support the ability to add a `PRIMARY KEY` to an `EXTERNAL TABLE`. However, as you are using Entity Framework there are a couple of ways you can get around this.

The easiest solution would be to decorate the required property on the entity with the the [KeyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute?view=netcore-3.1) and if necessary, the [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netcore-3.1) and or [ColumnAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute?view=netcore-3.1) like so:

```c-sharp
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Your other option would be to override [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) and use Fluent API to define your models properties:

```c-sharp
public class HumanResourcesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder):

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>
                    .HasKey(x => x.EmployeeId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>
                    .Property(x => x.EmployeeId)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
                    .HasColumnName("Id");
    }
}
```

If the options above are not viable, you could always create a local table with the same structure, apply the primary key to it and then generate your model. Once you have your model definition, you can go back into SQL Server drop the local table and then recreate it as an external table.

Comment: .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) seems to be obsolete, but UseIdentityColumn() should do the trick as well.

Comment: What we learn from all the thing that external table can not have an primary key, this is the limitation, we also understood we can use DbQuery instead of DbSet. And we also understood there is change in entity framework 3.x to define external table as DbQuery is obsolete.